# Multiple Imputation: Include Original Dataset?

Tags: spss, multiple-imputation

I am using SPSS and I'm currently working with a datafile that contains multiple imputation (40 imputations) because of missing data.

My question: Should I keep the original dataset (with missing values) in the analysis?

This seems to be default in SPSS and it seems to me that the pooled statistics include the original dataset. But is this correct or should I unselect/delete the original dataset?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The imputed data set will include the original data and the set of imputations. You don't want to remove the original data set, but the pooled statistics are based only on the imputed sets.